# why not use system timer on linux(timerfd)?

Tags: c++, linux, timer

I found that most of the server(for example, RPG web game server) always realize a timer by themselves instead of using system timer, for example on linux,

```
int timerfd_create(int clockid, int flags)
```

Could you tell me why ? I think the system api(timerfd_create) can have a higher performance.

Comment: If you are using C++11, check out the chrono library. I would think that one of the main reasons for that would be cross platform support - you cannot use a linux timer in windows or `QueryPerformanceCounter` for linux.

Answer (score 5):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Indeed, [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) is efficient, but it is Linux specific.

Using Posix timers with [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) et al. is probably more portable.

The dramatic advantage of the Linux specific `timerfd_create` (and also [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) & [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)...) is to be [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) friendly (since it is a file descriptor, like e.g. pipes or sockets are). However, most event loops are build above a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) which does accept a delay (milliseconds), or the older [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason not to. The system calls only became available since Linux 2.6.25 (2008), and library support did not appear until glibc 2.8 (2009). Given that most people learn how to write applications from their professors or existing open source projects, there are just a lack of practical examples up to now (2014).

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two potential reasons that I can think of to not use timerfds in a program:

1) The program is a server that maintains a large number of open connections. By default, Linux allows a process to have 1024 descriptors per process. This can be changed, however, the fact remains that file descriptors are not a free resource and if you have thousands of open socket connections, you will likely have at least that many timers in order to manage timeouts. All this adds up to a lot of descriptors.

2) There is probably more overhead to using timerfds than there would be to manage a set of timers in user space. Blocking on a call to select() or, more appropriately, epoll_wait(), involves a system call, while one could manage a large set of timers in user space without any such transitions, given that clock_gettime() doesn't require one.

http://linuxmogeb.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-does-clockgettime-work.html